# Are dwarves emotionally constricted?

Tags: magical-theory, dwarves, dragon-age

The basic premise of magic in [Dragon Age](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Age) is that it relies on a connection to "the Fade" -- an otherworldly realm where mortal logic doesn't hold sway. Humans and all the other sapient peoples have access to the Fade, which is evidenced by their ability to dream, and also by a small proportion of them having access to magic. The dwarves of the buried kingdom don't have access to the Fade, can't produce mage children, and *never dream*. This is stated to be because of their living in proximity to huge amounts of lyrium.

Tranquility is a lobotomy-like process (maybe simply a prefrontal lobotomy as we know it) which is designed to take away one's magical powers. As a side effect, it also precludes dreaming, which cuts off all access to demons. All tranquil mages shown have an extremely flat affect, in fact they are meant to be completely emotionless. This is also stated to be an effect of the rite of tranquility. Rumor has it that in the supplemental materials reversal of tranquility causes extreme emotional fluctuations.

From all these facts it would seem a logical conclusion that the dwarves of Orzammar (although not necessarily surface dwarves, I'm not quite sure what's going on there) are incapable of experiencing emotion. Yet many points of characterization would seem to contradict this. More than that, I would argue that the characters in question don't so much contradict the idea that dwarves are emotionally flat, as they indicate that the idea didn't surface in the writing process.

In summation: Do dwarves in Thedas have feelings? If so, how? If not, why?

Comment: What game is this?

Comment: @Lodewijk - "The basic premise of magic in **[Dragon Age](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Age)**..."

Comment: Whoops sorry. Skimming isn't flawless :s

Comment: @Lodewijk - Just edited to clarify this anyway

Comment: If all dwarves are sociopaths, they certainly do a good job at hiding it. (see: Varric Tethras, the smoothest dwarf in fiction) I don't have an explanation for how/why, but the answer to the first question is "yes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the Rite of Tranquility is a broad stroke that does far more damage to the brain than necessary. Long-term exposure to Lyrium would appear to suppress or even remove the connection to the Fade without affecting the subject's overall emotional state or control. In contrast, it would seem that tranquility (or rather, the process that makes a person tranquil) affects not only the Fade connection but also emotional state and/or control.

We must assume that Lyrium exposure only works over a longer period - otherwise, the mages would just use Lyrium to snip the Fade connection without any additional damage.

Unfortunately, we're left to speculate on much of this as the details of the tranquil state and/or the process for forcing it on someone simply aren't available. We know it's a long process (unlike, say, the rite to become a Warden), we know it's painful & life-altering, and we know that it can be performed with or without the subject's consent.

Personally, I'm betting on the "magical lobotomy" theory, myself. Which means that the dwarves are perfectly capable of a wide range of emotion, whereas Tranquils aren't.

Comment: I had had a few thoughts along this line, mostly focussed on whether magical ability could be 'localized' in the brain, and what that meant regarding lyrium-activated spirit magic. This does seem to be the only answer that adds up, except for one detail: in DAII the presence of a Fade spirit is enough to completely restore a tranquil mage's emotions. It seems the connection between emotion and the Fade isn't entirely assumed. I'm also unclear on why lyrium increases magical ability in the short term, but destroys it in the long term. The more I question the lore, the less I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that Dwarves are born that way, instead of having their connection to the Fade severed.